# linear programming and flow network

Tags: algorithms, linear-programming, network-flow

Here is the problem:
[image]

I have hard time understanding the problem ,  what does it mean by "conservation factors" and how to approach the problem using linear programming.

For what I understand, if a vertex have a total in_flow of 100, and the conservation factor is 50%-80%, then the total out_flow would be in between 50-80% of 100?

Answer (score 2):

1. > How to understand the conservation factors?

   It is clearly stated that `a[u] * f_in[u] <= f_out[u] <= b[u] * f_in[u]`, where `a[u]` and `b[u]` are some non-negative numbers. I do not understand what is unclear here.
2. > For what I understand, if a vertex have a total in_flow of 100, and the conservation factor is 50%-80%, then the total out_flow would be in between 50-80% of 100?

   Yes.
3. > How to solve it using linear programming?

   Let's create a variable for each edge(which represents the amount of flow that goes through it). Let's call it `x_i`. Then we have constrains for each vertex based on its conservation factors(`f_in` is the sum of variables for in-going edges and `f_out` is the sum for of variables for the out-going edges). These constraints are expressed as two linear inequalities for each vertex(except the source and the sink). We need to maximize `f_out[s]`, which is, again, a sum of `x_i` for some `i`(namely, for those edges that go out of this vertex). So we have reduced it to standard [linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) problem.